# Phrase Synonymous to "Stop at nothing?"

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

I'm writing a paper describing a fashion designer who creates incredibly complex and EXTRAVAGANT sets for his runway shows. I want to say he "stops at nothing" or "spares no effort" or "leaves no stone unturned" where his events are concerned. Any better phrases come to mind than these? Feel a bit clumsy still...

Comment: His sets are "out of this world."

Comment: 'Stop at nothing' suggests ruthless action. It would imply that the designer might be involved in sabotage, theft, black magic to get results.

Comment: How about either "pulls out all the stops" or "gives 110%"

Comment: Spares no expense?

Comment: yes thats also good thanks! @P1h3r1e3d13

Comment: In a less formal setting and perhaps it is slightly crude, you could say he goes "two nuts" or "balls to the wall".

Answer (score 1):

"Leave no stone unturned" is a pretty good one.

Answer (score 0):

> He ***gives it his all*** where his events are concerned.
>   He ***goes all out*** where his events are concerned.

Wiktionary:

> *Verb*
>   **[give one's all](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_one%27s_all)**
>   To make the utmost effort; **to contribute, using all of one's abilities and resources**.
>
> 1868, Louisa May Alcott, chapter 4, in Little Women:
>   "I'd go myself,
>   if I was any use. As I ain't, I give my boys, and give 'em free." He
>   spoke so cheerfully, looked so sincere, and seemed so glad to give his
>   all, that I was ashamed of myself.
>
> *Verb*
>   **[go all out](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_all_out#English)**
>   (*idiomatic*) To reserve nothing; to put forth all possible effort or resources.
>
> They went all out for his eightieth birthday party and chartered a
>   tour boat on the bay.